# making HTTPS connection with stream server

Tags: java, https, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I have a function where i send the URL for streaming.

```
hplayRadioStream("https://radio.itechnepal.com/pathibhara/stream");
```

So i've made connection with the server like this:

```
private static void hplayRadioStream(String spec) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, JavaLayerException {
      URL url= new URL(spec);
      HttpsURLConnection huc= (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      InputStream response= huc.getInputStream();
      Player player= new Player(response);
      player.play();

}
```

Now it sends back 403 error message. I am using JLayer to play the stream. Am i missing something here?? Even pasting this URL in browser sends the forbidden message.  Please do provide me some hints here.

Comment: 403 Access is forbidden. You need a username and password, then you need to install a `java.net.Authenticator` that knows them.

Comment: username and password for??

Comment: Err, to grant you access? Is this really such a mystery?

Comment: oh sorry i meant, username and password of the link https://radio.itechnepal.com/pathibhara/stream ?? Will i be provided with such credentials??